# Why (e^x-1)/x does not work properly, but (e^x-1)/log(e^x) does?

Tags: r, floating-point, computation, rounding-error

I would like to ask a question why computing value of (e^x-1)/x for numbers very close to zero does not work properly (for example if x=10^-15, result is 1.1102230), but when I use formula (e^x-1)/log(e^x), which is mathematical equivalent, it gives me correct result of 1.000000. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried (e^(x-1))/x?

Comment: But  the formula is supposed to be exactly as written (e^(x)-1)/x

Comment: you will probably see that in floating point log(e^x) != x therefore the computation is different. Try to print out every single operation made.

Comment: Isn't this just a complaint about the limitations of using floating point numbers with limited precision. There are packages that support higher precision.

Comment: @LorenzoBelli what do you mean by every single operation made?
I have only used a function in R to compute results:  
ex62b = function(k)
{
  x=10^-k
  return((exp(x)-1)/x)
}

ex62b(1:15)

ex62c = function(k)
{
  x=10^-k
  return((exp(x)-1)/log(exp(x)))
}
ex62c(1:15)
`
@BondedDust I understand that because of limited precision in computation the results are different. But I don't understand why the second formula is more accurate.

Comment: The formulas arent the same. The equivalent formula to the first one is ln(e^x) because by the ln properties ln(e^x) = x• ln e where ln e = 1 so x•1 = x

Comment: @GmloMalo by log I meant natural logaarithm, sorry for confussion (so we have same formula)

Comment: @GmloMalo The `log` in the OP's question is actually the natural (base e) logarithm. In maths it is written as `ln` but in programming languages virtually always written as `log`. (Even though `log` in maths is often taken to mean logarithm with base 10...)

Comment: is a possible reason that e^x and log(e^x) have the same rounding error using floating point arithmetic? Or something like that?

Comment: @WhiteViking ok thanks for the explanation. I was confused on that. :)

Comment: @Juraj sorry for the confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the first function exhibits what is known as *catastrophic cancellation*: for *x* near 0, *e<sup>x</sup>* is very close to *1 + x*. As floating point numbers are less dense near 1 than 0, the result of the expression *e<sup>x</sup> − 1* will be very close to *x*, but lose accuracy due to intermediate rounding.

The second exploits a neat trick of "cancelling out" the rounding error. In fact, this particular example is covered in detail in [section 1.14.1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7J52J4GrsJkC&lpg=PR3&ots=B4j2tlvA55&dq=Accuracy%20and%20Stability%20of%20Numerical%20Algorithms&lr&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Nicholas J. Higham's excellent book *Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms*. The crux of his explanation is

> The expression *(e<sup>x</sup> − 1) / x* cannot be accurately evaluated for a given *x ≈ 0* in floating point arithmetic, while the expression *(y − 1)* / log *y* *can* be be accurately evaluated for a given *y ≈ 1*. Since these functions are slowly varying near *x = 0* (*y = 1*), evaluating *(y − 1)* / log *y* with an accurate, if inexact, approximation to *y = e<sup>x</sup> ≈ 1* produces an accurate result.

Comment: This example is due to Kahan, who used it to illustrate what he called an anti-theorem: a theorem which is widely believed and widely taught but false. William M. Kahan, "Interval arithmetic options in the proposed IEEE floating point arithmetic standard". In: Karl L. E. Nickel, ed., *Interval Mathematics 1980*, Academic Press 1980, pp. 99-128. See "Anti-Theorem 1" on page 110.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is an R question, how about computing exp(x)-1 by calling expm1(x)? expm1() is an R function designed to return accurate values of exp(x)-1 even for values of x close to 0. expm1(x)/x gives you the right answer.